# Use wildcards in WASB ListBlobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure .Net SDK to list all blobs from Windows Azure Storage Blob container.

```
let client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient()
let container = client.GetContainerReference("my-container")
let list = container.ListBlobs("data/2014-*-17/", false) // ! here
```

as you can see i'm trying to filter blobs by wildcarded prefix.

**UPD** Not supported as 07/2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this won't work as Azure Storage does not allow you to do server-side `wild card` filtering. Only filtering option available to you server-side is `prefix` filtering.

So what you would do is list blobs names of which starts with `data/2014-` and then apply rest of the filtering logic on the client side once you received all blobs names of which start with `data/2014-`.

```
let list = container.ListBlobs("data/2014-", false) // ! here
//Do client side filtering on the "list"
```

Comment: sorry but i was not able to find `ListBlobs` on blob container. do i need to include some namespace?

Comment: @sairfan - Please ask a new question and provide all the details there.